# Let $A=\{2a:a\in\omega\}$ be the set of even natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define a relation ''~'' as follows:

$⟨n, m⟩\sim⟨k, l⟩\Leftrightarrow (n\setminus\ m)\cap A=(k\setminus\ l)\cap A$

find a complete system of representatives of the equivalence classes.

So after the definition $⟨3, 8⟩$ and $⟨2, 9⟩$ are in the same equivalence class, right ?

and we can always choose both numbers even(i.e. $⟨2, 8⟩$)

Therefore we get;

$\{⟨0, 1⟩,⟨0, 2⟩,⟨0, 4⟩,⟨2, 4⟩,⟨0, 6⟩,⟨2, 6⟩,⟨4, 6⟩,⟨0, 8⟩...\}$ is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that for any $m,n\in\omega,$ we have $$(n\setminus m)\cap A=\{j\in A:m\le j\text{ and }j<n\}.\tag{$\star$}$$

From $(\star)$, we see that the following are equivalent:

- $n\le m,$ or $m\in \omega\setminus A$ and $n=m+1.$
- $(n\setminus m)\cap A=\emptyset.$

This allows the description of one equivalence class (the only infinite equivalence class, in fact).

We can also see from $(\star)$ that in every equivalence class, there is a representative $\langle n,m\rangle$ such that $m,n\in A.$ Now, suppose that $m,n\in A$ such that $m<n,$ and let $k,l\in\omega$ such that $\langle n,m\rangle\sim\langle k,l\rangle.$ Since $m\in (n\setminus m)\cap A=(k\setminus l)\cap A,$ then $l\le m.$ There *cannot* be any even $j$ lying strictly between $l$ and $m$ (why?) so $m$ is at most $l+1$, and so $l\le m\le l+1.$ Since $n\in A$ and $n\notin (n\setminus m)\cap A=(k\setminus l)\cap A,$ then $k\le n$ (why?). However, $k\notin (k\setminus l)\cap A=(n\setminus m)\cap A,$ so since $n\in A,$ then $n$ is at most $k+1$ (why?), and so $k\le n\le k+1$. Hence, $\langle n,m\rangle$ represents an equivalence class of $4$ members whenever $m,n\in A$ such that $m<n.$

Then $$\mathcal R:=\bigl\{\langle 0,0\rangle\bigr\}\cup\bigl\{\langle n,m\rangle\in A\times A: m<n\bigr\}$$ gives a set of representatives of equivalence classes. It can be shown that

- each element of $\mathcal R$ represents a different equivalence class, and
- each equivalence class has a representative in $\mathcal R$.

Comment: Yes. I agree, but the set, i wrote in the last line, can this be a representationclass ?

Comment: Every single pair you wrote in the last line is in the same equivalence class. You want to find a system of representatives for *all* of the equivalence classes, though. I've modified my answer to make a suggestion. You'll need to prove the details.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve found part of one of the equivalence classes. That class actually contains every $\langle m,n\rangle$ such that $(m\setminus n)\cap A=\varnothing$, so it includes all pairs $\langle m,n\rangle$ with $m\le n$ and all pairs like $\langle 4,3\rangle$, with even first component one more than the second component. In other words, this class is

$$\begin{align*}
&\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:(m\setminus n)\cap A=\varnothing)=\\
&\qquad\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:m\le n\}\cup\{\langle 2n+2,2n+1\rangle:n\in\omega\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Since $\langle m,n\rangle\sim\langle k,\ell\rangle$ if and only if $(m\setminus n)\cap A=(k\setminus\ell)\cap A$, it’s this intersection $(m\setminus n)\cap A$, the set of even natural numbers in $m$ but not in $n$, that determines the equivalence class of $\langle m,n\rangle$. For each $\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega$ let $E(m,n)=(m\setminus n)\cap A$; then $\langle m,n\rangle\sim\langle k,\ell\rangle$ if and only if $E(m,n)=E(k,\ell)$. Thus, you’ll have an equivalence class for each possible value of $E(m,n)$.

- To find all of the equivalence classes, ask yourself what subsets of $A$ can be $E(m,n)$ for some $\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega$.

Comment: But we need only 1 representative of each equivalence class.

Comment: @derivative: According to what you wrote in the question, you are to find a **representation** of the equivalence classes; that’s not the same thing as finding one representative of each class. It requires you to find a nice description of the classes.

Comment: Sorry i translated it from german

Comment: @derivative: How does it read in the original German?

Comment: "repräsentantensystem"   https://user.math.uzh.ch/fachverein/fileadmin/documents/pruefungen/grundlagen/pruef_HS12.pdf here's the link exercise 3b

Comment: @derivative: Thanks. I’ve modified your translation in the original question so that it better reflects the German original.